# Want to take first date appearing for a certain task name in python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have an excel table that reads:

| Task Name | End Date | Process ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TASK 1 | 1st feb | 65461 |
| TASK 2 | 2nd feb | 65461 |
| TASK 1 | 3rd feb | 65461 |

and i have a code that matches the ID and takes in the date for task 1 but I want to take the first end date for that task in python. Below is my code:
'''

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.read_excel("Purchase Requisition and Purchase Order Approval Workflow Tasks.xlsx")
p_id,tk,ed =df1['Process ID'].tolist(),df1['Task Name'].tolist(),df1['End Date'].tolist()
ed = pd.to_datetime(df1['End Date'])
a = len(p_id)
x=np.array(p_id)
x=np.unique(p_id)
b=len(x)
inrfqdate=[None]*b
for i in range(0,b):
    for j in range(0,a):        
        if x[i] == p_id[j]:              
            if ("Initiate Purchase Requisition" in tk[j]):
                inrfqdate[i] = ed[j]
```

'''
This takes the end date for latest task name appearing. I jut want it to store the first task date.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a DataFrame I created to test my solution.

```
import pandas as pd

# Test Data Frame
data = {'Task Name': ['TASK 1', 'TASK 2', 'TASK 1', 'TASK 1', 'TASK 2', 'TASK 2'],
        'End Date': ['2/1/2021', '2/2/2021', '2/3/2021', '2/7/2021', '2/8/2021', 
                     '2/10/2021'],
        'Process ID': ['64561', '64561', '64561', '64562', '64562', '64562'],
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

That gave me the following table:

[image]

Then I changed the dtype in the `End Date` column from an Object to a DateTime and added an additional column to find the `Min Date` grouped by `Process ID` and `Task Name`

```
# Convert Date Column from Object to DateTime
df['End Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End Date'])

# Create a 'Min Date' column and groupby parameters to select minimum date
df['Min Date'] = df.groupby(['Process ID', 'Task Name'])['End Date'].transform('min')
```

That gave me the following output:

[image]

You could also replace the current data in `End Date` by using:

```
df['End Date'] = df.groupby(['Process ID', 'Task Name'])['End Date'].transform('min')
```

Comment: Did this answer your question? If so, you might want to give a +1 and select that it has been answered. Otherwise, comment what else you need.